# Modifying array of key value in JSON jq

Tags: json, shell, command-line, edit, jq

In case, I have an original json look like the following:

```
{
  "taskDefinition": {
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "web",
        "image": "my-image",
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "DB_HOST",
            "value": "localhost"
          },
          {
            "name": "DB_USERNAME",
            "value": "user"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And I would like to inplace modify the value for the matched key like so:

`jq '.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].environment[] | select(.name=="DB_USERNAME") | .value="new"' json`

I got the output

```
{
  "name": "DB_USERNAME",
  "value": "new"
}
```

But I want more like in-place modify or the whole json from the original with new value modified, like this:

```
{
      "taskDefinition": {
        "containerDefinitions": [
          {
            "name": "web",
            "image": "my-image",
            "environment": [
              {
                "name": "DB_HOST",
                "value": "localhost"
              },
              {
                "name": "DB_USERNAME",
                "value": "new"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Is it possible to do with `jq` or any known workaround?

Thank you.

**Updated**

For anyone looking for editing multi-values,
here is the approach I use

```
JQ=""
for e in DB_HOST=rds DB_USERNAME=xxx; do
    k=${e%=*}
    v=${e##*=}
    JQ+="(.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].environment[] | select(.name==\"$k\") | .value) |= \"$v\" | "
done

jq '${JQ%??}' json
```

I think there should be more concise way, but this seems working fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is enough to assign to the path, if you are using `|=`, e.g.

```
jq '
  (.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].environment[] | 
   select(.name=="DB_USERNAME") | .value) |= "new"
' infile.json
```

Output:

```json
{
  "taskDefinition": {
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "web",
        "image": "my-image",
        "environment": [
          {
            "name": "DB_HOST",
            "value": "localhost"
          },
          {
            "name": "DB_USERNAME",
            "value": "new"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution looks the most obvious to the question I had. I also do append for multi values modify based on your answer, please see the updated section in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a select-free solution using `|=`:

```
.taskDefinition.containerDefinitions[0].environment |=
  map(if .name=="DB_USERNAME" then .value = "new"
      else . end)
```

Avoiding `select` within the expression on the LHS of `|=` makes the solution more robust w.r.t. the version of jq being used.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to consider this alternative to using `|=`:

```
walk( if type=="object" and .name=="DB_USERNAME" 
      then .value="new" else . end)
```

Comment: Why aren't you merging your two answers?